Can i use Bun and Npm in one React project?
There's a React project I'm working on. I'm trying to integrate Bunjs as much as possible into this project. At the first stage, I thought of installing the project's packages with Bunjs. The packages appear to be installed with "bun install", but it gives the following error during the build phase. (Bun v1.1.4)

webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env stats=minimal

[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:

C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-     keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js:3:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js',
'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\workspace\my-app\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'`

In the first stage, I want to install the packages with "bun install". My main goal is to transfer the project completely from npm and webpack to bun
